# pass excel array constant to VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell whose value is an array constant,
for example cell A1 is set to `={1,2,3,4,5,6}`

I then defined a function in VBA:

```
Function MyFunc(Data)
MyFunc = Data.Rows.Count
End Function
```

I want the function to return the length of the array (6) when I can `=MyFunc(A1)`, but using the debugger, I find the 'Data' variable my function receives only contains the first element of this array.
`Data.Rows.Count` evaluates to 1 and `TypeName(Data)` evaluates to 'Range'

Comment: `Data` is not an array, but a `Range` object. `Range.Value` is an array only if the range is for more than a single cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And another method:

```
Function myFunc(Data)
    myFunc = UBound(Evaluate(Data.Formula))
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but I think you can just use `Split` here.

```
Function MyFunc(ByVal Data As Range) As Long
    Dim x
    x = Split(Data.Formula, ",")
    MyFunc = UBound(x) + 1
End Function
```

[image]

Obviously this can be made more robust (e.g. handle a multi-cell input), but I think it gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: I think that hard-coded comma needs to be `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree, add that to the list of things that "can be made more robust" :)

Answer (score 3):

May be

```
Function MyFunc(data As Range)
Dim x

x = Split(Mid(data.Formula, 3), ",")
MyFunc = UBound(x) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: I think that hard-coded comma needs to be `Application.International(xlListSeparator)`.